# How can I customize keyPreview and popUpKeyboard appearance without implementing KeyboardView form scratch?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, android-input-method, android-popupwindow

I'm trying to extend my custom `KeyboardView`. Is there any way to customize the `keyPreview` and `popUpKeyboard` appearance without implementing the `KeyboardView` from scratch ?

Answer (score 1):

The keyPreview is possible, just create your layout, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:textStyle="bold" >

</TextView>
```

and set this attribute in your keyboardView

```
android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview"
```

The popup keyboard is not, if you want to customize things like colors you have to implement your own keyboardView.